# Identifying individual peaks from find_peaks

Tags: python, scipy, time-series, signal-processing

I have successfully identified peaks in a 2D time-series signal (time vs intensity) using scipy.signal.find_peaks and have the peak properties generated by the function in a dictionary, including left and right base time values for each peak.

Now I would now like to go back to my original signal and identify the individual peaks.
I feel like there is probably a simple way to do it, but I cannot seem to find it.

The data looks like:

```py
Time (s) Intensity

0        0  
1        1        
2        3     
3        1       
4        0
5        0 
6        1 
7        5 
8        3 
9        1 
10       0
```

The left and right base values of the peaks on the time
(x) axis look like:

```py
left bases
1
6

right bases
3
9
```

The result would look like:

```py
Time (s) Intensity   Peak  

0        0           Nan       
1        1           Peak 1        
2        3           Peak 1        
3        1           Peak 1       
4        0           Nan
5        0           Nan
6        1           Peak 2
7        5           Peak 2
8        3           Peak 2
9        1           Peak 2
10       0           Nan
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to post your code, and likely the input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your left and right bases are respectively stored in lists `left_base` and `right_base` of the same length, and your data is stored in the `data` pandas DataFrame, you can iteratively assign each slices:

```
for left,right,index in zip(left_base,right_base,range(len(left_base))):
    data.loc[left:right,'Peak'] = "Peak {}".format(index+1)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much!